# Sleep Task on Form load not working

Tags: c#, winforms, parallel-processing, async-await, task

I am using the following code to apply a delay in my form load method before it becomes visible (after a splash screen is shown). I have defined my form load as `async`:

```
private async void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

And this is my delay function at the end of `MainForm_Load`:

```
Task startTimer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
});
await startTimer;            
splash.Close();
this.Visible = true;
```

But my delay function is not working, my splash screen is immediately closed and my form becomes visible. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**
Here is the code for my form load. But again I have removed some blocks from it so I won't give you the headache:

```
private async void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Visible = false;
    // Check license
    // Load two user controls
    Splash splash = new Splash();
    splash.Show();
    RefreshPostbagFolder();
    InitiateGeneralSettings();
    InitiateRunSelectFile();
    InitiateRunSelectManualCampaignType();
    InitiateImageList();
    RefreshManageTab();
    RefreshProgramLog();
    RefreshServiceLog();
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); });
    //await startTimer;            
    splash.Close();
    this.Visible = true;
    this.BringToFront();
}
```

Comment: You should look into how `multi-threading` works, and possibly into `backgroundworker`.

Comment: Given trick is similar to `await Task.Delay(5000);`.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks but can you see the error in my code first?

Comment: @Sinatr yes but still no effect.

Comment: @Pedram: There's really not a lot here to go on. Would need more code. Or, you could look in the direction I pointed you.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the issue.  This waits 5 seconds as expected: `await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); }); MessageBox.Show("foo");`

Comment: @David now the splash message disappears after five seconds but my form becomes visible before it is supposed to. my `this.Visible = true;` should happen after `await` is complete.

Comment: @Pedram: What did you change?  My two lines of code are still unable to replicate the issue.  Nothing after the `await` is invoked for 5 seconds.

Comment: @David I haven't changed anything. I just replaced your await with mine (they are basically the same thing). After the await, I have a `this.Visible = true;` but I think our Sleep function is overlooked. If I replace the Task with `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)` it works except that it is ugly and my splash screen becomes frozen.

Comment: @Pedram: Then we're essentially still at the point where I can't replicate the issue.  Which leads me to suspect that there's more going on in the code than what's shown in the question.  Awaiting the task always halts the code execution for me.

Comment: @David my form load is very big. But I just updated the question with a small version of my form load. Hope it helps!

Comment: @David fyi I commented the entire code of all other things between the first line `this.Visible = false;` and `Splash splash = new Splash();`. But the program still acts the same. So I don't think the code in between plays any role to disturb our task.

Comment: This should work. The question cannot be answered without a **short, executable** repro. Shortening the real code is not enough here. Voting to close since right now there is no basis for an answer.

Comment: @usr I wrote in the previous comment that I have commented out all the unnecessary parts in my code and it still does not work. So it is no longer short.

Comment: @usr: I've managed to replicate the issue (see my answer below).  The code in the question does demonstrate the problem, in an admittedly unintuitive way.

Comment: @Pedram where is the executable repro that I can run, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main form gets automatically shown and activated inside `Application.Run` [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Application.cs,d7cd7464da6bb836), note `applicationContext.MainForm.Visible = true`.

It becomes visible as soon as the execution point returns from `Form.Load` event handler to the code which fired the event (in your case, that's where it hits the `await` inside `MainForm_Load`), so the asynchronous part doesn't affect its visibility.

To avoid flickering, you can initially show the form as minimized and without the taskbar icon, like this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            var form = new Form { 
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized, 
                ShowInTaskbar = false };

            form.Shown += delegate 
            {
                Debug.Print("form.Shown");
            };

            form.Load += async delegate
            {
                Debug.Print("form.Load");

                var splashForm = new Form { Text = "Splash!" };
                splashForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                splashForm.Show();

                await Task.Delay(5000);

                splashForm.Hide();

                form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                form.ShowInTaskbar = true;

                form.Show();
            };

            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of modifying `Program.Main`, you can initially set `Form.WindowState` and `Form.ShowInTaskbar` in the VS form designer or your `MainForm`'s constructor.

On a side note, use `Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep` wrapped with `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Comment: This is very smart! I think I'll choose it as the answer. But instead of minimizing, I used `Opacity=0` and then used `Opacity=100` after putting back to normal because minimizing my main form caused my Splash form to be minimized too. But thank you very much. Now I have a solution finally.

Comment: @Pedram, you don't need to use opacity. I've updated the answer to show/hide a spash form.

Answer (score 2):

This is interesting, and I currently don't have an explanation for it.  I'm sure there's more to how WinForms works than simply setting these properties.  But this basic example *does* replicate the issue:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); });
    this.Show();
}
```

Stepping through the code in the debugger, what's *actually* happening isn't that the rest of the code isn't being awaited, but that the `Hide()` isn't doing what we think.  The form isn't actually displayed until *after* `Form1_Load` executes.  Since it executes asynchronously, the internal components which serve to display the form are able to execute during that `await`.  But that's too late to hide the form.

This shows promise:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        this.Hide();
    }));
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); });
    this.Show();
}
```

What this does is invoke `Hide()` after the components have shown the form.  However, the form is still shown for a fraction of a second.  So it's not ideal.

It's been a *long* time since I've done anything with WinForms (and even then I didn't do much), so I'm not sure how else to load a form without it being shown.  But this at least gets to the issue of why it's not "awaiting" in your case.  It *is* awaiting, but *during* that await is when the form is initially shown.  So hiding the form *before* that point has no effect.

Comment: This looks great! I put my `this.Visible = false` in an `Invoke`. Now the only problem is that fraction of a second appearing problem.

Comment: @Pedram: It looks like starting a form in a hidden state isn't as easy as one might think.  But this shows promise: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/175582/Start-a-WinForm-Hidden

Comment: @David that's a good trick actually. So instead of visible we should deal with Opacity.

Comment: @Pedram: If you find a better way it'll make for a good blog post to help future visitors :)

Comment: @David, I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28848678/1768303) might be a better option.